# ¿cómo evaluar cuando un valor de mi preferenceActivity es verdadero?

Tags: android, android-fragment, sharedpreferences

Tengo el siguiente fragmento, correspondiente a un PreferenceActivity:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Sesión">
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="preference_sesionAuto"
        android:summary="Permitirle a la aplicación que apenas inicie, inicie sesión sin ingresar las crendenciales. Sigue requeriendo conexion a internet."
        android:title="@string/SesionAuto" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:dependency="preference_sesionAuto"
        android:key="preference_MantenerSesion"
        android:summary="Si seleccionas esta opción, no se cerrará tu sesión hasta que tu decidas cerrarla desde el menú lateral."
        android:title="Mantener sesión iniciada" />
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Cuenta">
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="preference_modificarC"
        android:summary="Algún dato del cual nos proveíste ya no es correcto? entonces modifícalo para que tengamos actualizados tus datos."
        android:title="Modificar cuenta" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="preference_eliminarC"
        android:summary="Lamentamos mucho que te encuentres aquí, pero si lo que deseas es eliminar tu cuenta, estás a un solo toque de hacerlo."
        android:title="Eliminar cuenta" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Y el código del fragmento es el siguiente:

```
public static class UsuarioPreferenciaFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_usuario);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
                    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                                              String key) {
                            sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                            switch(key){
                                case"preference_modificarC":
                                    boolean modif=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("preference_modificarC",false);
                                    if(modif){
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Modificar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//Sólo es de ejemplo
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case"preference_eliminarC":
                                    boolean borrar=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("preference_eliminarC",false);
                                    if(borrar){
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Borrar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //sólo es de ejemplo 
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActConfiguracion.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

bien, mi problema está en que quisiera que el `onSharedPreferenceChanged` que declaro en el código, me ayude a saber **cuando el valor de mi preferencia es `true`**, pero por alguna razón, el método no funciona en el lugar donde lo tengo colocado, ***¿porqué no funciona el método?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema que tenés es que creates el `listener` pero no está asignado a ningún lado.

No estoy muy familiarizado con este tipo de actividad pero de la documentación deberias hacer algo así después de crear el listener in `onCreate()`:

```
PreferenceManager pm = getPreferenceManager();
SharedPreferences sp = pm.getSharedPreferences();
sp.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(spChanged );
```

Comment: era exactamente lo que necesitaba, gracias.